# How To Know When A C# Socket Server Has Sent The Full Message

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a remote TCP/IP socket that I am calling in C# with the below code:

```
public static async Task UseSocketClass(string ipString, int port, string message)
{
    string response = "";
    int received;
    try
    {
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipString);
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new(ip, port);
        using Socket client = new Socket(ipEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        await client.ConnectAsync(ipEndPoint);
        int messageLength = message.Length;
        var messageLenghtBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(messageLength));
        var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        byte[] finalMessageBytes = messageLenghtBytes.Concat(messageBytes).ToArray();
        client.SendTimeout = 10000;
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
        _ = await client.SendAsync(finalMessageBytes, SocketFlags.None);
        Console.WriteLine($"Socket client sent message: \"{message}\"");
        var buffer = new byte[1024];

        do
        {
            received = client.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
            Console.WriteLine($"Received length => {received}");
            response = response + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, received);
        } while (received > 0);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
            Console.WriteLine($"Socket response => {response}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Socket response is empty.");

        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Response So Far => {response}");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType() + " => " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I am able to send the message to the remote port and receive responses.
The issue is the exit condition of my do-while loop. I noticed that the integer 'received' never falls to 0.

So, even once I have received the full message from the server, I still stay in the loop until my set timeout period elapses.
I had the idea that maybe I could use this: `while (received > 1024);` as my exit condition, but sometimes the 'received' integer drops below 1024 and then goes right back up to 1024 in the next loop iteration.

In short, how can I exit the loop after completely reading the server's response.

Comment: TCP doesn't do messages. It does an endless stream of bytes. If you want to detect the end of a "message", it's up to *you* to implement message framing or move to a higher level protocol which *is* oriented about exchanging messages, possibly atop TCP. The only time `Receive` will return `0` is *when the other end shuts down*, and you don't tend to want to do that after each message.

Comment: There is no way to know. The server has to tell you. What kind of server is it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Definitely agree with you. Try implementing a framing mechanism or in simple terms, data you begin and end a message with. You can then check for that data when receiving a message from the server.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Unfortunately i have no control over changing what the server sends to me meaning i can't configure the server to tell me when the relevant part of the stream stops. So what I have decided to do is use an initial timeout of ```client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;``` and then receive the first set of data. Afterwards, i can set the timeout to ```client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;```  or less and then enter the loop. It's not ideal but it fits the business requirements.

Comment: The message *to* the server is using length prefix message framing. I would expect the message *from* the server to also use length prefix message framing.

Comment: @StephenCleary You're right. I note that the server returns ```9\``` appended at the front of the actual message. On wireshack, this looks like ```00 07 39 5c``` which seems to be little endian notation that represents the relevant length of the response that the server is sending back ie. ```473436``` characters

Comment: So there you go - loop until you've received four bytes, decode that length, then loop until you've received `length` additional bytes, then decode. BTW, don't decode UTF-8 piecemeal as you're doing - you've no guarantee that a multi-byte character won't be split at the boundaries. If you do need to do piecemeal decoding, you need to use a [Decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.getdecoder?view=net-7.0) to maintain state between calls.

Comment: I have [some sample code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html) that may help. It is somewhat dated and slightly inefficient (making more copies than strictly necessary), but it gets the general idea across.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not sure how i would go about using the a decoder while also using the received length of characters as my loop's exit condition. [Here](https://pastebin.com/R2ckQ6rj) is my most recent version of the code.